# How do I create a dataset for vacation home bookings?

Tags: r, categorical-data, data-transformation, dataset, variable

My family is renting out a vacation home and I would like to create a dataset in R to calculate statistics on the bookings (for some helpful insights and also for me to practice R).
I have a question now on how to create that dataset. Right now the booking data is stored in an excel file and the x axis (columns names) are the dates (e.g. Jan 1st 2018) and the bookings are marked there. The names of the bookings and additional information (like if they took a dog with them) is stored in a comment. The season (high season, middle season, low season) which is important for pricing is color coded.

Now I thought to make a useful R dataset it might make sense to have all variables that are of interest as column names and each bookings (=cases) as rows. I saw an example data set for hotel bookings online that used arrival date, departure date etc. as variable names.

My question is now though - for us it is very important to know which season the booking was in. I was thinking of creating a categorical variable "seasons" with each season as a category, the problem it though, that some bookings are not only in one season, but since I don't have the structure anymore using the dates, but simply but an arrival and departure date, I'm not sure how to deal with these cases.

Probably there's a really simple solution, but I'm new to this and not sure what to do.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.